# Automapper: how to map many members using a property of source type?

Tags: c#, automapper

```
// source classes
public class User 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserStatus 
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

// dest classes
public class UserVM 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserStatusVM : UserVM 
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

//Automapper configuration
c.CreateMap<User, UserVM>();
c.CreateMap<UserStatus, UserStatusVM>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Status))
  .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.ResolveUsing(source => Mapper.Map<User, UserVM>(source.User))); // error there
```

My target is all members (excluding `Status` one) of `UserStatusVM` were mapped from `User` property of `UserStatus` class just as if it's mapping `Users -> UserVM`.

How can I achieve it? Is something like `ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.User.Id))` etc. the only solution?

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Flattening.html

Answer (score 1):

Rename `UserVM`'s  properties

```
public class UserVM 
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

`UserId` and `UserName` will be mapped **by convention** from `UserStatus.User.Id` and `UserStatus.User.Name` respectively.

*Note*

While mapping, Automapper sees that `UserVM.UserId` does not exits on `UserStatus` type, so it splits `UserId` into `User` and `Id` (by CamelCase) and maps `UserVM.UserId` from `UserStatus.User.Id`